# Set width of unknown item to its full width in transition

Tags: css, transition

I have span element. In it i have an unknown amount of small 16x16 images. all in one line.

If i set width to auto it takes its full width properly.

Thing is though, I want to do a transition. So I set the width to 10px. And then on hover i set it to 100%, this is bad as it takes 100% of width of hte parent container. So I thought to set it to `auto` but it doesnt animate. Is there a solution to this?
fiddle: mouseover the light blue block at right with three red boxes in it: http://jsfiddle.net/q37ek3nx/4/

Fiddle link above.

Snippet of fiddle:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <span class="img"></span>
        <span class="img"></span>
        <span class="img"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<style>
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    background-color: midnightblue;
    text-align: right;
}

div > span {
    background-color: steelblue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    transition: width 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div > span:hover {
    width: 100%;
}

.img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

edit:
im thinking of setting it to `width: calc(auto)`? maybe will work?

edit: calc auto did not work: http://jsfiddle.net/q37ek3nx/

Comment: Can you put what you have so far into a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) as well as post your example in a snippet and add to your question?

Comment: Ive run into this problem before, because transition requires two numerical values ti go back and forth from. I ended up using JS to grab the outer width.

Comment: Added the snippet. Yeah man Im trying to avoid js :( I was hoping calc(auto + 0px) would do it :(

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this is using transitions on `max-width`. On hover you must apply an always greater with than the biggest possible. The more difference with the actual width, the faster the transition will be.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/q37ek3nx/3/

It's not perfect, it would be great to know certain limits this width could get to, but it works and it's still pure CSS. Otherwise you should use JS, because transitioning `scaleX` (the only other way to "transition to auto") wouldn't get the behavior you intend.

Comment: That's nice thanks for this. However you can tell the transition animation is odd. As its still growing to 200px but its just cut off. I tried to set `max-width: auto` and set on hover to `width:100%` and that didnt work but nice idea man.

Comment: Glad you liked it! It also occurred to me that you could count the number of images and place it in an attribute, an then do animate to: `width: calc(16px*attr(data-total))` but seems like right now browsers don't support `attr()` anywhere but in `content`. Such a shame.

Comment: oh my gosh!! that is genius!!!! thats a great temp solution!!! im actually making a firefox-addon so this works!! thank you! edit: oops nevr mind :( nice thought tho